# How to make use of Android AdMob lifecycle events

Tags: android, admob, ads, amazon-product-api

Admob is providing the option of when the ad is opened, closed, loading etc... But what is the benefit of it?. How can we make use of this through the android app.

The syntax of life cycle events looks like. I want the uses in the real android app

```
public abstract class AdListener {
    public void onAdLoaded();
    public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode);
    public void onAdOpened();
    public void onAdClosed();
    public void onAdLeftApplication();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A few examples:

`onAdLoaded()`: if you would like to show an ad as soon as it is loaded, you can do it here

`onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode)`: the ad is failed to load, you can handle it here as you wish, check the `errorCode`, request a new ad etc.

`onAdOpened()`: the ad is opened, you can start loading a new one in the background

etc.

The usage depends on what you would like to achieve.

Check out the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdListener) of `AdListener` to see when these methods are called.